# Filtering NSArray having Dictionary inside it - swift 1.2

Tags: ios, swift, filter, nsarray, nsmutabledictionary

```
(
        {
        "creation_date" = "23-02-2016 18:29";
        filename = "abc.pdf";
    },
        {
        "creation_date" = "23-02-2016 18:28";
        filename = "32.pdf";
    },
        {
        "creation_date" = "23-02-2016 18:28";
        filename = "78.pdf";
    },
        {
        "creation_date" = "23-02-2016 17:28";
        filename = "65.pdf";
    },
        {
        "creation_date" = "23-02-2016 16:48";
        filename = "6.pdf";
    }
)
```

I have NSArray like this. I want Filtered NSArray of NSMutableDictionary which has filename = SearchString. Means I am using searchBarController, so when I will search something it should filter array having that searched filename in dictionaries.
How can I do that? Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var fileterArray: NSArray = yourArray.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(NSPredicate(format: "self.%@ contains[c] %@", "filename", "SearchString"))

print(fileterArray)
```

Comment: search string is text which I will type in searchbar

Comment: When I want to filter [String]() array.. I was using this code..        `filteredArray = fileList.filter({ (country) -> Bool in
           let countryText: NSString = country                                          return (countryText.rangeOfString(searchString, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch).location) != NSNotFound
        })`

Comment: check updated answer. and let me know if working or not...!